# Allow const member function to edit some member variable using mutable

Tags: c++, c++11, memoization, mutable

I want to apply the [Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) technique to increase performance of a "Line" class which was like this:

```
class line{
    public:
        line() = default;
        ~line() = default;

        float segment_length() const;

        Tpoint first;
        Tpoint second;
    };
```

As you see, the member function `segment_length` is marked as `const` because it just compute the length and does not affect the class. However, after applying the Memoization, the class line became:

```
class line{
    public:
        line() = default;
        ~line() = default;

        float segment_length();

        Tpoint first;
        Tpoint second;

    private:
        float norm_of_line_cashed = -1; //for optimization issue
    };
```

The member function`segment_length` is not const anymore becuase it is alter the `norm_of_line_cashed` memebnre variable.

**The question:**

what is the correct manner in this case:

- Leave `segment_length` as `non-const` member function.
- Make it `const` again and mark `norm_of_line_cashed` as `mutable`.

Comment: Does `line` have to work in multi-thread environment ?

Comment: Yes and No, the whole process could be called in parallel but each process would have its own lines. So, no more than one thread is accessing the same line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would mark `segment_length` as `const` and mark `norm_of_line_cashed`* as `mutable`.

This is following the concept of *logical constness* rather than *bitwise* or *physical constness*. You are only modifying internal state which won't be visible to the outside world, so logical constness is preserved even though you are technically modifying your class. This is exactly what `mutable` is made for and this seems like a solid design choice.

One note: you might want to have some `bool` variable (or [`std::experimental::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional)) to keep track of whether you have a value cached rather than relying on a flag values which are fragile and can lead to headaches in the future.

*maybe you meant "cached".

Comment: Yes, I think I am worrying about money so much those days :D Thanks for the answer.

Comment: And the bool flag can be replaced by `optional`.

Comment: Note that since C++11, the standard library has the right to expect that `const` operations are thread-safe. So the `mutable norm_of_line_cached` should somehow be synchronised - atomic or protected by a mutex or some such.